# how to get the first element from a List - Beginner

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have a `List <Hotel>` object, and it has 1o elements in it. Now i need to print all the values stored in this List object.

The code i tried is as follows;

```
List <Hotel> hotels;
... i have included the getters and setters for the above List of hotels

int x = getHotels.size(); 
System.outprintln("SIZE = "+ x + " hotel index 2 name " + getHotels.get(2).getHotelName());
```

When i execute the program the x value gets displayed, but when i add `getHotels.get(2).getHotelName()` i get a Nullpoint Exception. How do i resolve this.

Comment: btw, that code would not compile. if `getHotels` is a method, then it should be used with `getHotels()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the `List` implementation, for example `ArrayList` permits `null` elements.

So it might be some `null` elements on your List, even if it has 10 members.
To ovoid null pointer exception, simply check if current element is a null.

```
for (Hotel hotel: hotels) {
    if (hotel != null) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Another cause might be your `hotel.getHotelName()` returns `null`,
Make sure you have set the hotel name at index 2 before.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the element at index `2` (which is the 3rd element) is `null`. Iterating collections is usually done with the for-each loop:

```
for (Hotel hotel : hotels) {
   // do something with each hotel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

List, like many other things, in Java are zero-based. If the List is of size 2 then `getHotels.get(0)` and `getHotels.get(1)` return the first and second elements in the list.

Comment: There are 10 elements in the List. so the 2nd index should display